# Flash won't display in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, flash-cs4

I have a problem with my site in internet explorer. It works fine in firefox, opera etc.
Sometimes internet explorer won't show my flash banner. For example when I'm on home page it works fine, but when i press services it doesn't show the banner. My web site is www.md-telmark.hr   ..... to view the page you should press the dot in the exclamation point in the "site under construction" picture.

Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). It's a good way to embed Flash content onto web pages. Works well in all browsers.

Comment: SWFObject FTW!  I suspect it had something to do with your wmode setting.